# Correlated column is not allowed in predicate in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I have two tables

**trade_table** as

| id | start_date | transacted_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2022-02-14 | 2022-02-17 |
| A1 | 2022-02-17 | 2022-02-25 |
| A5 | 2022-02-15 | 2022-02-19 |
| A6 | 2022-02-21 | NULL |

and
**trading_days** as

| trade_date |
| --- |
| 2022-02-14 |
| 2022-02-15 |
| 2022-02-16 |
| 2022-02-17 |
| 2022-02-19 |
| 2022-02-21 |
| 2022-02-23 |
| 2022-02-25 |

How to get actual date difference from trade_date table based on values from transacted_date and start_date from trade_table.

Expected Output table

| id | start_date | transacted_date | transact_in_days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2022-02-14 | 2022-02-17 | 3 |
| A1 | 2022-02-17 | 2022-02-25 | 4 |
| A2 | 2022-02-15 | 2022-02-19 | 3 |
| A6 | 2022-02-21 | NULL | null |

I tried this Spark sql query

```
sql_query = """ SELECT
  id,
  start_date,
  transacted_date,
  CASE
    WHEN transacted_date IS NULL THEN NULL
    ELSE (
      select
        count(1) -1
      from
        trading_days
      where
        trade_date between start_date
        and transacted_date
    )
  END as transact_in_days
from
  trade_table"""

df_spark = spark.sql(sql_query)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: outer join the two tables using the date bound logic, then group by the relevant columns.

For example:

```py
sql_query = """ 
    SELECT 
       id, 
       start_date, 
       transacted_date, 
       count(1)-1 transact_in_days 
    FROM 
         trade_table t
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT trade_date FROM trading_days) td ON 
         td.trade_date between t.start_date and t.transacted_date
         and transacted_date IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
       id, 
       start_date, 
       transacted_date

    """
df_spark = spark.sql(sql_query)
```

Comment: Differenece ie  transact_in_days is coming out to be absurd values

Comment: take a look at this sql fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a0ca07/3

Comment: added a bit more logic to account for potential reasons you are getting incorrect values